# Line extending beyond its div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML:

```css
.row.justify-content-center div:last-child>div>div {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="align-text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-1 text-center">
            <div id="step-1" class="circle">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                <p class="small">Step 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 text-center">
            <div id="step-2" class="circle">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                <p class="small">Step 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 text-center">
            <div id="step-3" class="circle">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                <p class="small">Step 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I switch to smaller screens (eg. IPhone 12), this is what I get:

[image: Steps]

The line's width is set to 100%. So why does it extend beyond its div and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: _"and how can I fix the problem?"_ - probably not by changing anything about the width - because if your "Step X" texts get displayed _below_ each other, then having that _horizontal_ line doesn't make much sense any more to begin with, I suppose? Should turn into a vertical line than anyway.

Comment: Steps displayed under each other is a second problem due to the line extending way beyond its container. I'm hiding the text on smaller screens now too.

Comment: When I emulate a small screen, your steps are still below each other, even if I set the lines to `display:none`, removing them completely. The steps are below each other because you used `col-sm-1`, so _below_ that breakpoint, they all take full width.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect these changes.

Comment: I suspect this may be a responsive problem - given that when you're transitioning to a smaller screen, the resolution obviously changes messing up the css.

Consider testing using `@media only screen and (max-width: desired screen size here(px))`

Answer (score 0):

The line has position absolute, it follows relative parent which is col-sm-1 and not circle class element. Remove this position absolute will make width follow circle element instead

Comment: If I remove `position` the line does not extend to the next circle.